# Perform a macro by Checkbox Input

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007, word-2003

I have `Check-Boxes` with caption of country Names and a `OK` button on `User-form`,

[image]

User will `Mark` required `Check-Boxes` and click `OK` to submit the form.

**Expected Result:** For each checked `Box` there is a `Macro` to perform.

How do I make `OK` button to perform macro on Selected Countries which are Check-Marked by User?

and

Is the following code correctly handle the situation? or there is other way of doing that?

```
If ActiveDocument.CeemeaFinallist.EasternEurope("CheckBox1").CheckBox.Value = True Then
Application.Run MacroName:="Normal.NewMacros.CEEMEA2"
Else
End If
```

[image]

How do I `Select all` `Check-Boxes` at once?

Comment: Put it inside the button's click event? Not clear what you're asking...

Comment: It makes more sense now.  Wasn't sure if you were asking how to make the button fire the macro or if you were asking how to make it work through all the checkboxes.

Comment: step 1: user checked marks 
step 2: user click `ok` step 3: after ok vba will perform macro on marked countries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try iterating over the controls and firing the macro where the checkbox is set to True:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ctl As Control
Dim j As Long
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        If Me.Controls(ctl.Name).Value = True Then
            ' Fire macro with ctl.Caption to identify the country
        End If
    End If
Next    
End Sub
```

Comment: how do I `Select All` checkbox in single click.

Comment: Add a checkbox called Select All and in its click event, where its value is true, set all the individual checkboxes to true.  You could use similar code to the answer provided above.

Comment: I think `Select All` is another question that's why I added new question. kindly take a look at my Question related to Select All.[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315117/more-than-one-select-all-checkboxes-for-each-frame)