# more than one Select All Checkboxes for each frame

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007, word-2003

Following `Userform` has 4 (Four) `Select All` `Check-boxes`.

1. SelectAllE for Eastern Europe
2. SelectAllA for Middle East & Africa
3. SelectAllL for Latin America & Caribbean
4. SA         for Select All Regions (Working)

only the fourth one is working correctly

[image: Userform]

Following are codes for each Checkboxes

```
Private Sub SA_Click() ' this one is working Correctly
Dim ctl As Control
Dim j As Long
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
    If Me.Controls(ctl.Name).Value = True Then

    Me.Bulgaria.Value = True
    Me.Croatia.Value = True
    Me.Croatia.Value = True
    Me.czechrepublic.Value = True
    Me.Estonia.Value = True
    Me.Hungary.Value = True
    Me.Latvia.Value = True
    Me.Lithuania.Value = True
    Me.Macedonia.Value = True
    Me.Poland.Value = True
    Me.Romania.Value = True
    Me.Russia.Value = True
    Me.Ukraine.Value = True

    Me.Bahrain.Value = True
    Me.CoteD.Value = True
    Me.Egypt.Value = True
    Me.Ghana.Value = True
    Me.Iraq.Value = True
    Me.Kenya.Value = True
    Me.Kuwait.Value = True
    Me.Morocco.Value = True
    Me.Namibia.Value = True
    Me.Nigeria.Value = True
    Me.Oman.Value = True
    Me.Palestine.Value = True
    Me.Qatar.Value = True
    Me.Rwanda.Value = True
    Me.SaudiArabia.Value = True
    Me.Turkey.Value = True
    Me.Uganda.Value = True
    Me.UAE.Value = True
    Me.Zimbabwe.Value = True

    Me.Chile.Value = True
    Me.Mexico.Value = True
    Me.Colombia.Value = True

    Else
    Me.Bulgaria.Value = False
    Me.Croatia.Value = False
    Me.Croatia.Value = False
    Me.czechrepublic.Value = False
    Me.Estonia.Value = False
    Me.Hungary.Value = False
    Me.Latvia.Value = False
    Me.Lithuania.Value = False
    Me.Macedonia.Value = False
    Me.Poland.Value = False
    Me.Romania.Value = False
    Me.Russia.Value = False
    Me.Ukraine.Value = False

    Me.Bahrain.Value = False
    Me.CoteD.Value = False
    Me.Egypt.Value = False
    Me.Ghana.Value = False
    Me.Iraq.Value = False
    Me.Kenya.Value = False
    Me.Kuwait.Value = False
    Me.Morocco.Value = False
    Me.Namibia.Value = False
    Me.Nigeria.Value = False
    Me.Oman.Value = False
    Me.Palestine.Value = False
    Me.Qatar.Value = False
    Me.Rwanda.Value = False
    Me.SaudiArabia.Value = False
    Me.Turkey.Value = False
    Me.Uganda.Value = False
    Me.UAE.Value = False
    Me.Zimbabwe.Value = False
    End If
End If
Next
End Sub

Private Sub SelectallE_Click() ' this one is not working Correctly
Dim ctl As Control
Dim j As Long
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
    If Me.Controls(ctl.Name).Value = True Then
    Me.Bulgaria.Value = True
    Me.Croatia.Value = True
    Me.Croatia.Value = True
    Me.czechrepublic.Value = True
    Me.Estonia.Value = True
    Me.Hungary.Value = True
    Me.Latvia.Value = True
    Me.Lithuania.Value = True
    Me.Macedonia.Value = True
    Me.Poland.Value = True
    Me.Romania.Value = True
    Me.Russia.Value = True
    Me.Ukraine.Value = True
    Else
    Me.Bulgaria.Value = False
    Me.Croatia.Value = False
    Me.Croatia.Value = False
    Me.czechrepublic.Value = False
    Me.Estonia.Value = False
    Me.Hungary.Value = False
    Me.Latvia.Value = False
    Me.Lithuania.Value = False
    Me.Macedonia.Value = False
    Me.Poland.Value = False
    Me.Romania.Value = False
    Me.Russia.Value = False
    Me.Ukraine.Value = False

    Me.Chile.Value = False
    Me.Mexico.Value = False
    Me.Colombia.Value = False

    End If
 End If
Next
End Sub

Private Sub SelectAllA_Click() ' this one is not working Correctly
Dim ctl As Control
Dim j As Long
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
    If Me.Controls(ctl.Name).Value = True Then
    Me.Bahrain.Value = True
    Me.CoteD.Value = True
    Me.Egypt.Value = True
    Me.Ghana.Value = True
    Me.Iraq.Value = True
    Me.Kenya.Value = True
    Me.Kuwait.Value = True
    Me.Morocco.Value = True
    Me.Namibia.Value = True
    Me.Nigeria.Value = True
    Me.Oman.Value = True
    Me.Palestine.Value = True
    Me.Qatar.Value = True
    Me.Rwanda.Value = True
    Me.SaudiArabia.Value = True
    Me.Turkey.Value = True
    Me.Uganda.Value = True
    Me.UAE.Value = True
    Me.Zimbabwe.Value = True
    Else
    Me.Bahrain.Value = False
    Me.CoteD.Value = False
    Me.Egypt.Value = False
    Me.Ghana.Value = False
    Me.Iraq.Value = False
    Me.Kenya.Value = False
    Me.Kuwait.Value = False
    Me.Morocco.Value = False
    Me.Namibia.Value = False
    Me.Nigeria.Value = False
    Me.Oman.Value = False
    Me.Palestine.Value = False
    Me.Qatar.Value = False
    Me.Rwanda.Value = False
    Me.SaudiArabia.Value = False
    Me.Turkey.Value = False
    Me.Uganda.Value = False
    Me.UAE.Value = False
    Me.Zimbabwe.Value = False
    End If
  End If
Next
End Sub

Private Sub SelectAllL_Click() ' this one is not working Correctly
Dim ctl As Control
Dim j As Long
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
    If Me.Controls(ctl.Name).Value = True Then
    Me.Chile.Value = True
    Me.Mexico.Value = True
    Me.Colombia.Value = True
    Else
    Me.Chile.Value = False
    Me.Mexico.Value = False
    Me.Colombia.Value = False
    End If
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is too complicated, why not keeping it more simple? Since you are inside the Click event you know the control and don't need to loop each control of the userform!

```
Private Sub SA_Click()
    SelectAllA.Value = SA.Value
    SelectAllL.Value = SA.Value
    SelectallE.Value = SA.Value
End Sub

Private Sub SelectallE_Click()
    Bulgaria.Value = SelectallE.Value
    Croatia.Value = SelectallE.Value
    Croatia.Value = SelectallE.Value
    czechrepublic.Value = SelectallE.Value
    Estonia.Value = SelectallE.Value
    Hungary.Value = SelectallE.Value
    Latvia.Value = SelectallE.Value
    Lithuania.Value = SelectallE.Value
    Macedonia.Value = SelectallE.Value
    Poland.Value = SelectallE.Value
    Romania.Value = SelectallE.Value
    Russia.Value = SelectallE.Value
    Ukraine.Value = SelectallE.Value
End Sub

Private Sub SelectAllA_Click()
    Bahrain.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    CoteD.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    Egypt.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    Ghana.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    Iraq.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    Kenya.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    Kuwait.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    Morocco.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    Namibia.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    Nigeria.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    Oman.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    Palestine.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    Qatar.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    Rwanda.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    SaudiArabia.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    Turkey.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    Uganda.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    UAE.Value = SelectAllA.Value
    Zimbabwe.Value = SelectAllA.Value
End Sub

Private Sub SelectAllL_Click()
    Chile.Value = SelectAllL.Value
    Mexico.Value = SelectAllL.Value
    Colombia.Value = SelectAllL.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: I've changed a little the behavior for the Global Select All check box.